# Are there any tools to monitor network requests at very low-level?

Tags: opensuse, ftp, http, zypper

I would like to monitor the web/ftp requests made by Zypper when we install a package. But none of the suggested network monitoring tools seem to identify the requests made by Zypper.
So far, I've tried

- netstat
- conntrackd
- argus
- ntop
- nethogs

and a few more.
But none of them seem to detect the web requests made by Zypper. Or maybe I'm not using these tools in the right way?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you may use:

- strace -e trace=network : to trace network related operations
- lsof / netstat to list open connections
- wireshark/tcpdump to capture network traffic (you need to know
- iptables to count packets/bytes to specific addresses/ports reached by Zypper traffic once you know those destinations.

Comment: Might need to add the `-f` option to strace. I think zypper calls `curl` or `aria2c` to do the actual downloading.